# noise reduction using python regarding other people's sound as noise

Tags: python, pca, voice-recognition, noise, noise-reduction

I want to use python to dispose of an Audio file which can recognize only my voice. For example, I speak to a raspberry pi car about "forward". It will go straight but other people who speak "forward" cannot control my car.

or I want to regard another person's sounds as noise and eliminate it. How can I do? someone told me can use pca or ica to reduce those noisy.

Answer (score 0):

You first recognize the command then extract the speaker with i-vector or d-vector to identify you.

You can find description of the algorithms [in Apple's blog](https://machinelearning.apple.com/2018/04/16/personalized-hey-siri.html), for example. You can find implementation of the mentioned algorithms in [Kaldi](https://kaldi-asr.org), they are not very easy to integrate though.

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand that very cleverly. Do you mean that invoke the car with some specific phrases like "Hi Siri" which trained use my voice and if it recognizes correct then recognizes commands and run those command?